# I'm new to Perl and have a few regex questions

Tags: html, perl, screen-scraping

I'm teaching myself Perl and I learn best by example.  As such, I'm studying a simple Perl script that scrapes a specific blog and have found myself confused about a couple of the regex statements.  The script looks for the following chunks of html:

```
 <dt><a name="2004-10-25"><strong>October 25th</strong></a></dt>
 <dd>
   <p>
     [Content]
   </p>
 </dd>
 ... and so on.
```

and here's the example script I'm studying:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use XML::RSS;
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::Entities;

my $rss = new XML::RSS (version => '1.0');
my $url = "http://www.linux.org.uk/~telsa/Diary/diary.html";
my $page = get($url);

$rss->channel(title       => "The more accurate diary. Really.",
          link        => $url,
          description => "Telsa's diary of life with a hacker:" 
                 . " the current ramblings");

foreach (split ('<dt>', $page))
{
if (/<a\sname="
         ([^"]*)     # Anchor name
         ">
         <strong>
         ([^>]*)     # Post title
         <\/strong><\/a><\/dt>\s*<dd>
         (.*)        # Body of post
         <\/dd>/six)
{
    $rss->add_item(title       => $2,
               link        => "$url#$1",
                   description => encode_entities($3));
}
}
```

If you have a moment to better help me understand, my questions are:

1. how does the following line work:

   ([^"]*)     # Anchor name
2. how does the following line work:

   ([^>]*)     # Post title
3. what does the "six" mean in the following line:

   </dd>/six)

Thanks so much in advance for all your help!  I'm also researching the answers to my own questions at the moment, but was hoping someone could give me a boost!

Comment: The Post title bit looks like it should be `([^<]*)`

Comment: I know you're new to Perl, but 'what does "six" mean?' reminds me of the urban legend of the guy who simplified sinx/cosx to in/co

Comment: Please realize that this is a bad example.  HTML is not a regular language, so regular expressions are not a good tool for parsing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how does the following line work...
>
> ([^"]*) # Anchor name

zero or more things which aren't ", captured as $1, $2, or whatever, depending on the number of brackets ( in we are.

> how does the following line work...
>
> ([^>]*) # Post title

zero or more things which aren't >, captured as $1, $2, or whatever.

> what does the "six" mean in the
>   following line...
>
> </dd>/six)

- s = match as single line (this just means that "." matches everything, including \n, which it would not do otherwise)
- i = match case insensitive
- x = ignore whitespace in regex.

`x` also makes it possible to put comments into the regex itself, so the things like `# Post title` there are just comments.

See [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more / better information. The link is for Perl 5.10. If you don't have Perl 5.10 you should look at the perlre document for your version of Perl instead.

Comment: "match as single line" is not very informative.  /s means . matches any character, including newline, instead of the default any character except newline.

Comment: @ysth: I've altered it as you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

1. `[^"]*` means "any string of zero or more characters that doesn't contain a quotation mark". This is surrounded by quotes making forming a quoted string, the kind that follows `<a name=`
2. `[^>]*` is similar to the above, it means any string that doesn't contain `>`. Note here that you probably mean `[^<]`, to match until the opening `<` for the next tag, not including the actual opening.
3. that's a collection of php specific regexp flags. I know `i` means case insensitive, not sure about the rest.

Comment: re: #3 - No, it's not PHP-specific.  They're flags used by PCRE regex libraries, which are available for many different languages.  See the documentation at http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt for full details of PCRE.  (PCRE = Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions)

Comment: regardless, I still don't know what they all mean :)

Answer (score 1):

1. The code is an extended regex.  It allows you to put whitespace and comments in your regexes.  See perldoc [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) and [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Embedding-comments-and-modifiers-in-a-regular-expression).  Otherwise like normal.
2. Same.
3. The characters are [regex modifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers).